# How can I make Jetty 9 ignore keypass while accesing keystore?

Tags: ssl, jetty, ssl-certificate, keytool

How can I make Jetty 9 ignore keypass while accesing keystore?

Here is what I did:

- I generated certificate for my domain at startssl.com
- I generated chained certificate (mine + sub.class1.server.ca.pem + ca.pem) like this `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ssl.key -in /home/ubuntu/bundle.crt -out /home/ubuntu/bundle.pkcs12`
- Imported them into new keystore like this: `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /home/ubuntu/bundle.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore /opt/jetty/etc/keystore`
- For some reason alias was "1" so I renamed it to "jetty" like this `keytool -changealias -alias "1" -destalias "jetty" -keystore /opt/jetty/etc/keystore -storepass storepwd`
- Note that I use `storepwd` which is default password for Jetty distro

My `jetty-ssl.xml` contains this

```
<Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
  <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.keystore" default="etc/keystore"/></Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.keystore.password" default="OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4"/></Set>
  <Set name="KeyManagerPassword"><Property name="jetty.keymanager.password" default="OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g"/></Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.truststore" default="etc/keystore"/></Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.truststore.password" default="OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4"/></Set>
  <Set name="EndpointIdentificationAlgorithm"></Set>
  <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
    <Array type="String">
      <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5</Item>
      <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>

  <New id="sslHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Arg><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
    <Call name="addCustomizer">
      <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
    </Call>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

Now when I launch all this beauty Jetty crashes with following error

```
2013-07-11 21:34:01.984:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED SslContextFactory@e45a028(/opt/jetty/etc/keystore,/opt/jetty/etc/keystore): java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:138)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:792)
    at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:131)
    at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:259)
```

Which is apparently password mismatch because it expects/passes keypass `keypwd` from default keystore that comes with Jetty.

Here is my certicifates(s): http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=p8LhT50P
It's output from `keytool -list -keystore /opt/jetty/etc/keystore -storepass storepwd -storetype JKS -v`

Where is it set? How can I fix this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two passwords involved: the keystore password (`KeyStorePassword`) and the key password (`KeyManagerPassword`). For PKCS#12 store, they are the same.

Since you've imported the key from the PKCS#12 store into the JKS store using the keystore's password, that doesn't mean that the password of the key itself was changed, and it's probably not `"keypwd"` (Jetty's default). Try to replace the value of `KeyManagerPassword` with your PKCS#12 store's password.

(Note that in general, you don't need to convert the keystore, you could have used `PKCS12` as the KeyStoreType.)

Comment: Would it be possible to ignore keymanagerPassword? I have not set key-password and that results in the console asking me for org.eclipse.jetty.ssl.keypassword which if left blank results in NPE :|

Comment: I +1 for "KeyManagerPassword = key password".